# Python Socket, No Data Received after Initial Transmission

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm looking to make a very basic remote desktop application. Right now I am able to capture the screen data using the python win32 API, and I am able to send one image over the socket connection, and rebuild it correctly on the receiving end. I send the size of the image and some other data encoded as an 11 byte string before sending the actual image data. The problem I am having is when I try to send the second 11 character string. Simply, no data is coming through the socket. The client sends the data, prints out some information confirming its progress and then closes. but on the server side, no data is coming through to the socket. I am not sure what is going on.

Here is my code, comments in line:

Client Side:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 8888))

imgLength = sys.getsizeof(bmpstr)    ## bmpstr is the pixel data
prefix = str(imgLength) # message length
prefixSize = sys.getsizeof(prefix)
if prefixSize < 30:
    prefix = ('0' * (30 - prefixSize)) + prefix
    prefix = "5" + "1" + prefix  ## BLOCK LOCATION    
s.send(prefix.encode("UTF-8"))

totalSent = 0
while totalSent < imgLength:
    totalSent += 4096
    if (totalSent >= imgLength):
        s.send(bmpstr[totalSent :])
        break
    else:
        s.send(bmpstr[totalSent : totalSent + 4096])
```

Right now I simply run this twice, sending the prefix and pixel data the same way. Its literally copy and paste. I don't close socket s, I use the same connection for both images. I'm wondering if maybe that is my problem? I am hoping to have a somewhat realtime transmission of data, maybe 3-4 FPS, so I would like to do this as efficiently as possible.

Server Side:

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8888))
serversocket.listen(5)

transmission = clientsocket.recv(4096)
transmissionMetaData = decode_meta_data(transmission)
transmissionLength = transmissionMetaData[0]
blockX = transmissionMetaData[1]
blockY = transmissionMetaData[2]

while 1:
    thisData = clientsocket.recv(4096)
    data += thisData
    if len(data) >= transmissionLength or not(thisData):
        break

## rebuild the image...

# prepare for second image
data = ""
transmission = ""
prefixTransmission = ""

## here is the problem, I am trying to receive the prefix data which will contain 
# the size of the second transmission. But for some reason this never gets any data
# it works just fine when i do it above.
while 1:
    thisData = clientsocket.recv(4096)
    prefixTransmission += thisData
    ### this line always prints an empty string for the data
    print sys.getsizeof(prefixTransmission), "   :", prefixTransmission
    if sys.getsizeof(prefixTransmission) >= 32:
        transmissionMetaData = prefixTransmission[0:11]
        if sys.getsizeof(prefixTransmission) > 32:  
            data = prefixTransmission[11:]
        break

transmissionMetaData = decode_meta_data(transmission)
transmissionLength = transmissionMetaData[0]
blockX = transmissionMetaData[1]
blockY = transmissionMetaData[2]

while 1:
    thisData = clientsocket.recv(4096)
    data += thisData
    if len(data) >= transmissionLength or not(thisData):
        break
```

So my current problem is that the second piece of meta data is simply not coming through the socket. If I just send the 11 character meta data, then the program hangs with an empty transmission. If I have the client send the 11 character meta data, followed by the image data itself, the server crashed because it cannot decode the first 11 bytes.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' cannot decode byte 0xff in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I think maybe I am pulling out the 11 characters improperly?

Comment: To ease your efforts, you might look into ZeroMQ; there is a stable Python bindings implementation (which also plays perfectly well with Gevent); ZeroMQ would probably make the task of message exchange between two nodes of your application much easier than using sockets. (ZeroMQ works peer-to-peer, i.e. is serverless, so there is no additional overhead to using it)

Comment: I don't see how is it suppsoed to continue working as there is no permanent loop anywhere to receive data from socket?

Comment: The problem is that the meta data, which will contain the size of the data to be sent is not being built correctly, or I am not recieving it correctly. I also realized there was a typo in my code, see above for correction and more explanation.

Comment: There is a *serious* misunderstanding about what `sys.getsizeof` means demonstrated by this code.  The function you are looking for is the builtin `len`.

Comment: That may be true, but as far as I can tell that part of the code is working correctly. I am pulling out the first 11 bytes from the incoming message. The length of the hex representation being 22 confirms this. getsizeof(...) == 32 and len(...) == 11 are the same in this instance, since python strings have 21 bytes of overhead. I think the problem is these bytes do not form a UTF8 string, even though I think they should.